# display text file in using excel 2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display the contents of a text file in `notepad++` on the screen using line below the `vba`. Currently the rest of the `vba` runs and I can see the text file to be displayed in the directory `var`, which has the path to the directory, but only `notepad++` opens and does not display the file.  Is there a better way rather then `Call Shell` as I can not seem to fix this or what am I doing wrong?  Thank you :).

**vba**

```
'UPDATE PERL VARIABLES USING SHELL '
Dim PerlCommand As String, PerlParameters As String, VarDirectory As String
Dim var As String, var1 As String, var2 As String, var3 As String

VarDirectory = "N:\path\to\data\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy")

var = VarDirectory
var1 = "sample_descriptor.txt"
var2 = "C:\cygwin\home\user\test_probes8.txt"
var3 = var & "\" & "output.txt"
var4 = var & "\" & "list_spikeins.txt" 'MATCH '

'CALL PERL '
 PerlCommand = """C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\file\perl.bat"""
 PerlParameters = """" & var & """" & " " & _
"""" & var1 & """" & " " & _
"""" & var2 & """" & " " & _
"""" & var3 & """" & " " & _
"""" & var4 & """"

CreateObject("wscript.shell").Run PerlCommand & "  " & PerlParameters, windowsStyle, waitOnReturn
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss") 'SECONDS ELAPSED '
MsgBox "The ImaGene and the spike-in verification process completed in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes" & " " & "these are the values:", vbInformation 'NOTIFY IN MINUTES '
   Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe " & "var" & "\" & "list_spikeins.txt", vbNormalFocus) ' DISPLAY IN NOTEPAD++ '
```

Comment: use  `& var &` not `& "var" &`

Comment: @Fadi.... Thank you very much :)